# Qual è il significato di "tenersi in mezzo" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia del nuovo cognome* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Ma che Bruno puntasse a me non mi convinse. Non mi aveva mai nemmeno guardata. Oltre al fatto che, se avesse avuto le mire che diceva Lila, sarebbe venuto lui all’appuntamento e non Nino. O almeno sarebbero venuti insieme. E comunque, vero o no, non mi piaceva: troppo basso, troppo ricciuto, senza fronte, denti da lupo. No e no. **Tenermi in mezzo**, pensai. Farò così.

Malgrado abbia cercato "mezzo" in alcuni dizionari, non riesco a capire il significato dell'espressione "tenersi in mezzo" nel brano precedente. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il significato di questa espressione è figurato: "tenersi in mezzo" vuol dire stare a metà strada tra un punto e un altro. Mi sembra di capire che la questione sia: "piaccio a Bruno oppure no?". Il personaggio si interroga, prova a valutare le due opzioni e poi decide di tenersi in mezzo, né sì né no, in attesa - immagino - di ulteriori elementi per capire la situazione.